# PUT to an array in existing collection

Tags: postman

The following is the schema of my API end-point. I want to test a PUT using PostMan, where I add a "skill".

How would you enter the information in Postman so that you are just passing a new "skill" to the model?

```
{
  "_id": "579a6fa26a0b6484172ae284",
  "firstname": "Max",
  "lastname": "Headron",
      "skills": [
         {"skill":"Can Type", "level":"Great"},
         {"skill":"Can Run", "level":"Good"},
  ]
}
```

Would you use dot notation in a form field. So instead of adding "firstname", which is at the top level of the object, you might enter "skills.skill" and the "value".

Hopefully this is a clearer description.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the body of the request.

[image: Postman doc link]

See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests.

Comment: Hi Erwin. I want to do a PUT into an existing record and insert into the "Contact" array.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the implementation of the API endpoint?